# Why is edit item greyed out on lookup link

Tags: lookup-column, list-item

This is SharePoint 2010 Enterprise. This is all OOB stuff.

I have one DocLib and two Lists. DocLib 1, List A, List B. DocLib 1 has two lookup columns. One to list A and one to list B. I have values in both of these columns on DocLib 1. When I click on linked value, it pops up modal form. Value going to List B has edit item button. Value going to list A has edit item button too but it's greyed out. I would like for users to use this popup form to edit both lists from the DocLib.

Any ideas why one is greyed out and how to enable it? I have full control permission on DocLib and both lists. I have tried comparing settings on both lists but everything looks the same.

I can't post picture yet, but I uploaded one here:
[http://imgur.com/nJ9YIS7](https://imgur.com/nJ9YIS7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never did figure this out, but I "fixed" it by recreating List A and recreating the lookup column. After doing so I could edit through the lookup link fine. (sharepoint bug I guess)